# Clojure generate externs ext.js files for ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, parsing, clojure, stream, clojurescript

I'm trying to parse some Javascript libraries with Clojure to generate externs files for using them in ClojureScript.

### Clojure read-file function

I stumbled across and [old Clojure source file](https://gist.github.com/Chouser/5796967) that intended to do this, but has some deprecated code and doesn't work anymore, so I wanted to take some concepts from it and start over.

From the script of the Gists above I started with the read-file function.

```
(ns n01se.externs-for-cljs
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [cljs.compiler :as comp]
            [cljs.analyzer :as ana]))

    (defn read-file [file]
      (let [eof (Object.)]
        (with-open [stream (clojure.lang.LineNumberingPushbackReader. (io/reader file))]
          (vec (take-while #(not= % eof)
                           (repeatedly #(read stream false eof)))))))
```

**First Question:** why eof is represented by a plain Object ?

### Parsing Javascript

Then I fed this Javascript source code to the `read-test-file` function:

```
yayQuery = function() { // <= EXCEPTION: read exception at {
    var yay = {};
    yay.sayHello = function(message) {
    console.log(message);
    }

    yay.getMessage = function() {
    return 'Hello, world!';
    }

    return yay;
};
```

I startup the cider debugger and start checking the loop and as expected I get `yayQuery`.

[image: First debug loop]

So I got:

1. yayQuery
2. =
3. function
4. ()

Until the reader gets to `{`, and this exception pops up.

`Map literal must contain an equal number of forms`.

### Prevent read from "evaluating" ?

**Hypothesis:** Looks like the `read` function tries to interpret `{` so starts searching for a key ?

**Second Question:** If the hypothesis above is true. Can I avoid read from evaluating the code ?

I tried binding `*read-eval*` to false but I still got the same exception:

```
(ns externer.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:gen-class))

(defn read-test-file [file]
  (let [eof (Object.)]
    (with-open [stream (clojure.lang.LineNumberingPushbackReader. (io/reader file))]
      (binding [*read-eval* false]
        (take-while #(not= % eof)
                    (repeatedly #(read stream false eof)))))))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (read-test-file (first args)))
```

I also tried [edn](https://github.com/clojure/tools.reader) also because of the [unsafety of using read](http://www.learningclojure.com/2013/02/clojures-reader-is-unsafe.html) but I still got the same exception as above.

```
(ns externer.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:gen-class))

(defn read-test-file [file]
  (let [eof (Object.)]
    (with-open [stream (clojure.lang.LineNumberingPushbackReader. (io/reader file))]
        (take-while #(not= % eof)
                    (repeatedly #(edn/read {:eof eof} stream))))))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (read-test-file (first args)))
```

**Final Question:** There's another more safe/correct way to generate externs automatically ?

Comment: http://michaelmclellan.me/javascript-externs-generator/ sometimes works

Comment: object is just a sentinel... a unique value that can't be read from the file. It seems like in your question you are reading JavaScript but using EDN/Clojure reading.

Comment: Thank you for the generator, two hours of googling and I didn't found it. Yes I start figuring out that EDN is for Clojure reading only. There's a sort of template mechanism for other type of data like Javascript so it can evaluate Javascript code ?

Comment: https://github.com/jmmk/javascript-externs-generator is written in Clojure, so you can look at the source code for inspiration as to how to parse JavaScript in Clojure, and perhaps adapt it if it is missing features you need.

Comment: opps upon closer inspection that generator is ClojureScript and it uses a trick by loading the JavaScript and looking at defined things... so not really parsing sorry. I'm not aware of any parsers... If you are interested in parsers, check out Instaparse

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, starred and forked the Clojure externs generator. I'll give a look at Instaparse never heard of that.